# getActionCommand not working in code (watching tutorial series)

Tags: java, jquery, youtube, actionlistener

I'm watching a youtube tutorial series by mybringback. (38th video in the series). At the very bottom of the code, I have e.getactioncommand.  When I click on the radio button, I want it to say something in the text field.  For instance when I hit radio button 1, it should say "you selected radio button 1" in the text field.  I followed the tutorial exactly, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

I have the driver class as well.  that i didn't post here.

Here;s the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pjS_IiNp008&list=SPDAA5DE54FB5215EC

```
      package ActionCommandnActionListeners;

      import java.awt.BorderLayout;
      import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
        import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
        import java.awt.Insets;
        import java.awt.Label;
        import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
         import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

           import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
       import javax.swing.JButton;
       import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
       import javax.swing.JFrame;
       import javax.swing.JLabel;
        import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
      import javax.swing.JPanel;
      import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
      import javax.swing.JTextArea;
      import javax.swing.JTextField;







    public class FirstWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

String s;
JCheckBox cb, cb2;
JTextField textField;
JLabel label;
JRadioButton b1, b2, b3, b4;
ButtonGroup group;
JTextArea tb;

public FirstWindow() {
    super("Your Computer is very special");

    setSize(600, 400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel p3 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    JPanel p4 = new JPanel();

    b1 = new JRadioButton("Choice 1");
    b1.setActionCommand("you selected num1");
    b1.addActionListener(this);

    b2 = new JRadioButton("Choice 2");
    b2.setActionCommand("you selected num2");
    b2.addActionListener(this);

    b3 = new JRadioButton("Choice 3");
    b3.setActionCommand("you selected num3");
    b3.addActionListener(this);

    b4 = new JRadioButton("Choice 4");
    b4.setActionCommand("you selected num4");
    b4.addActionListener(this);

    group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(b1);
    group.add(b2);
    group.add(b3);
    group.add(b4);

    p4.add(b1);
    p4.add(b2);
    p4.add(b3);
    p4.add(b4);

    JButton b = new JButton("Button 1");
    JButton c = new JButton("Button 2");

    p.add(b);
    p.add(c);

    cb = new JCheckBox("Do you LOVE bacon?");
    cb2 = new JCheckBox("Do you LOVE cheese?");

    p2.add(cb);
    p2.add(cb2);

    label = new JLabel("This is a label");
    JTextArea tb = new JTextArea("This is a text area");
    textField = new JTextField("text field");

    c.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String s2 = textField.getText();
            label.setText(s2);
        }
    });

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.insets = new Insets(15, 15, 15, 15);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    p3.add(label, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    p3.add(tb, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    p3.add(textField, gbc);

    add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(p2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(p3, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(p4, BorderLayout.WEST);

    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            s = "Good job kid, you harvested your corn! \n";

            if (cb.isSelected()) {
                s += " And of course you love bacon! \n";
            }
            if (cb2.isSelected()) {
                s += " Most naturally you love cheese! \n";
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    tb.setText(e.getActionCommand());

}
```

}

Comment: Any help would be appreciated.  Sorry if the formatting is sloppy. I;m new to this site.

Comment: The formatting has nothing to do with this site (or any other site). Be consistent with your code and always uses spaces or tabs, but don't mix the two.

Comment: Ok.  I'll try.  Hopefully my question was clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JTextArea tb = new JTextArea("This is a text area");
```

You are `shadowing` your variables. You defined the "tb" variable as an instance variable and a local variable. You don't want the local variable because your actionPerformed() method can't reference local variables.

So the code should be:

```
//JTextArea tb = new JTextArea("This is a text area");
tb = new JTextArea("This is a text area");
```

> I'm watching a youtube tutorial series by mybringback

I've never quite figured out why people use youtube for tutorials.

I would start with the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). This way not only can you read the tutorial at your pace but you can actually download the code and compile and test and change the code. So you start with working code and then you customize it to do what you want.

Comment: OMG!  Thanks!  That worked perfectly.  I remember when he did something like that in the tutorial, but i forgot to get rid of the JTextArea when I declared it at the top of the code.  I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out that tutorial as well.  I like mybringback, he explains things well.  I've been reading the Java book by Lewis and watching his tutorials on myprogramming lab.  But his writing is a little dry for a noob like me. I find watching tutorials is helpful and it reinforced what I read.